# org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils and Selenium 3.6.0

Tags: java, selenium

I used org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils with Selenium 3.5.3 and all works great.
When I've changed Selenium version to 3.6.0, in my code line

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
```

is greyed out (inactive), and i've got errors:

```
Error: java: package org.apache.commons.io does not exist
Error: java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable FilenameUtils
```

What is wrong? Is it a bug in Selenium 3.6.0 or should I check something else?

Comment: Please try adding apache commons-io in classpath and try to build project.

Comment: what java version you are using? if its 7 then 3.6.0 will not support. upgrade your java version to 8

Comment: How do you run it? Through Eclipse?

Comment: I use it in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2 and Java 1.8.0_144 I've tried to launch from maven, but with the same result. Error: package org.apache.commons.io does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You relied on a *transitive dependency*, so Selenium 3.5.3 has (obviously) a dependency to `commons-io`, while Selenium 3.6.0 has not.

Although transitive dependencies are available for use in your module, relying on transitive dependencies is rarely a good idea. For each library you are explicitly using, you should have an explicit dependency in your Maven POM (what you added now as a - correct - solution).

Comment: Thanks Florian for full explaination!

Comment: @Krzysztof you should either mark mine or (preferably) your answer as the correct one to help others stumbling over this problem.

Comment: OK, I checked it :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything started works fine, when I added in POM.xml file dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem Here. Apache commons IO package is missing in 3.6 selenium. U can find that missing jar file in any previous version of selenium. just add that jar file into build path and it works fine.